# How to allow browser refresh when hosting Angular 4 app with Azure blobs and Azure Functions Proxies

Tags: angular, azure-blob-storage, azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

I've used angular-cli to build my Angular app.

Note I'm using PathLocationStrategy routing strategy, and due to other constraints I can't use HashLocationStrategy.

I've uploaded all static files into a "frontend" container in Azure Storage Blobs. The app is working fine except two limitations I've encountered:

1. User have to type to complete URL, and not only the domain name (i.e. https://someblob.blob.core.windows.net/frontend/index.html)
2. When user press browser refresh a 404 error is returned.

Using Azure Functions Proxies and the following proxies.json file I've managed to solve the first limitation. I.e. user can access the app by browsing some-azure-function.azurewebsites.net. But not the second one.

Is there a way to also solve the second limitation using Azure Functions Proxies?

proxies.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
  "proxies": {
    "refresh": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "route": "/frontend/"
      },
      "backendUri": "https://someblob.blob.core.windows.net/frontend/index.html"
    },
    "allfiles": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "route": "/frontend/{*rest}"
      },
      "backendUri": "https://someblob.blob.core.windows.net/frontend/{rest}"
    },
    "root": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "route": "/"
      },
      "backendUri": "https://someblob.blob.core.windows.net/frontend/index.html"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're running into an issue with angular code appending route info behind the URL, and blob storage being unable to serve that file.

Your middle proxy will append the whole URL text in a request to blob storage, so a request like `https://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/frontend/index.html/foo/bar' will send a request to blob storage as`https://someblob.blob.core.windows.net/frontent/index.html/foo/bar`

Either updating your middle proxy to a backend Uri of `https://someblob.blob.core.windows.net/frontent/index.html` and have every page redirect back to the homepage, or change the matchcondition to parse out the extra info.

`"route": "https://someblob.blob.core.windows.net/frontend/frontend/{page}/{*rest}"` will capture the page name in {page}

Comment: i need the middle proxy to transfer files such as js and assets. if I change it to redirect to index.html files won't be served. To narrow it down, I need a way to distinguish between a file and a path. if an extension exists, fetch the file, otherwise redirect to index.html. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Did you receive my previous comment?

Comment: I believe formatting your route as so will catch only routes with file extensions. `https://someblob.blob.core.windows.net/frontend/{page}.{ext}/{*rest}`